# MongoDB insert "$currentDate" field

Tags: mongodb, datetime

Can someone please help me with this problem related MongoDB C# driver:

I have a field that updates automatically with the date from the server. But it works only when I update the document.

This works (because is update (?)):

```
 IMongoUpdate update = new UpdateDocument(new BsonDocument().Add("$currentDate", new BsonDocument().Add("lastModified", true)
                        .Add("lastModifiedTS", new BsonDocument("$type", "timestamp"))).Add(new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("$set", new BsonDocument().Add("altered", alteredElementValue))));

var updateResult = _collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", key), update);
```

This does not work (this is an insert):

```
  _collection.Save(bson.First().Add(new UpdateDocument(new BsonDocument().Add("$currentDate", new BsonDocument().Add("lastModified", true)
                        .Add("lastModifiedTS", new BsonDocument("$type", "timestamp"))))));
```

But when i insert the document it gives this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.WriteConcernException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll
Additional information: WriteConcern detected an error 
'The dollar ($) prefixed field '$currentDate' in '$currentDate' is not valid for storage.'.
 (Response was { "ok" : 1, "code" : 52, "err" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$currentDate' in '$currentDate' is not valid for storage.", "n" : NumberLong(0), "updatedExisting" : false }).
```

Can it be because MOngoDB supports this kind of fields only for update ?

Comment: It could be for the exact error response you have been given. You cannot have fields in a document that begin with `$`. This is reserved for operators so fields cannot be named this way. Do you possibly have this in reverse? So you actually mean to save the "current timestamp" to the "lastModified" field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It's a bug. MongoDb doesn't support `$currentDate` for `insert`:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13695